# Publishing only the built .sln files artifacts in TeamCity

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

We have a git repository that contains about 6 .sln files.
Each solution has around ~ 15 projects.

We also use TeamCity to poll our git repository and build in case any changes are found.

I'd like to enhance our build with the following:

1. Build **ONLY** the projects that were actually changed by a commit.
2. Publish **ONLY** the outputs that were changed as build artifacts (in TeamCity).

For example, if a developer changes files in 2 different projects, only those projects get rebuilt, and only their outputs will be copied off to some location as the current build's outputs.

The first point is possible using the "**Build**" target, however i couldn't find a way to copy only the built projects' outputs off somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do it out of the box, nor I'm aware of a relevant plugin. However, you can achieve the desired result by comparing new binaries produced by the build with previous ones and publishing only those that differ.

You should use a diff tool that is aware of EXE and DLL file structure and can ignore things that change on every build - timestamps, PDB guids, signatures, etc. This problem has been discussed here on SO several times. For example, [Deterministic builds under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180852/deterministic-builds-under-windows).

Comment: The build produces around 600 files. I assume that testing each against an older version (that may be stored on some net drive) would be insanely slow?

Comment: You can consider storing a hash for each file produced by the build, and compare hashes. Again, the hash function has to be aware of PE file structure and ignore fields that change on every compilation. Something like dumpbin > RemoveChangingStuff.bat > CalculateHash.

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity provides VCS Trigger Rules which you can use to only trigger builds when files under a certain path within a repo are changed. You can use these rules in conjunction with Checkout Rules which are used to fine tune what is actually pulled down from the repo.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/VCS+Checkout+Rules

VCS trigger/checkout rules are defined at the Build Configuration level.  In theory, you could monitor changes within a single project, triggering a build against that project's .csproj file. Your artifact is simply that single project's output. In practice though, you're probably not going to want a Build Configuration per project.

6 solutions within a single repo kind of smells like you migrated from something like SVN or TFS.  If at all possible, I'd recommend you put each sln in its own Git repo. If you are using the 6 slns to "manage" a monolithic app with 90 projects then you have some other challenges.

Hope this helps but some more info about your repo and projects would be helpful!