# Compiled on 32-bit and 64-bit but checksum is different

Tags: c

Two binaries were compiled. One is on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine and other is on a 64-bit Windows 10. All the source files and dependencies are the same; however, after compilation the checksum was compared and they are different. Could someone provide an explanation as to why?

Comment: Are you comparing a 32-bit build and a 64-bit build and wondering why the binaries are different? If the checksums were the same you'd have a problem. The machine instructions are going to be vastly different.

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same? I feel like you're making an assumption that doesn't hold.

Comment: Unless you've taken specific measures to achieve [reproducible builds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1180852/11683), they are going to be different even on the same machine.

Comment: Even compiling twice on the same machine might not give the same checksum, since some compilers have the annoying habit of putting a time stamp into the executable.

Comment: @Siguza I would like to know why, the science behind it. I never said I expected them to be the same, I said "after compilation the checksum was compared and they are different". Please help with the science behind this outcome.

Comment: @Siguza If you read the post correctly you probably wouldn't have had that feeling.

Comment: @VictorS Asking why they differ implies that you expect them not to be.

Comment: @dbush it was merely an observation not implying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're comparing a 32-bit build and a 64-bit build you'll need to keep in mind that the compiled code will be almost completely different. 64-bit [x86_64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) and 32-bit [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) machine code will not only vary considerably, but even if that was not the case, remember that pointers are *twice the size* in 64-bit code, so a lot of code will be structured differently and addresses in the code will be expressed as bigger pointers.

The technical reason is the *machine code* is not the same between different architectures. Intel x86, and x86_64 have considerable variation in how the opcodes are expressed, and in how programs are structured internally. If you want to read up on the differences there's a lot of published material that can explain, like [Intel's own references](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf).

As others have pointed out building twice on the same machine may not even produce a byte-for-byte matching binary. There will be slight differences in it, especially if there's a code-signing step.

In short, you can't do this and expect them to match.

Answer (score 1):

> All the source files and dependencies are the same; however, after compilation the checksum was compared and they are different.

The checksum is calculated from the binary code that the compiler produces, not the source code. If ***anything*** is different, you should get a different checksum. Changes in the *source code* will change the binary, so a different checksum. But using a different *compiler* will also produce a different binary. Using the same compiler with different *options* will produce a different binary. Compiling the same program with the same compiler and the same compiler options on a different *machine* might produce a different binary. Compiling the same program for different *processor architectures* will *definitely* produce a different binary.